# I can't span class my &times alert (bootstrap) in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get the close button to appear on the right side.  Right now the close button "x" is appearing above my "success message"

I've tried placing the span in multiple places and in multiple ways but can't figure this out.

```
var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</span></div>';
```

The close button continues to show above the message no matter what i try.

Comment: Are you using boostrap? If so which version?

Comment: yes i am using bootstrap 4

Comment: Incorrect `span` and `button` closing tags.

Comment: Did you also link the bootstrap js? While your mark-up is currently incorrect, the close button should still be functional

Comment: I linked bootstrap.  What is the correct markup?.  I see someone else said incorrect span and button closing tags..

Comment: close button is functional it just won't align right

Answer (score 2):

Your code generates this:

```
<div class="alert {messageAlert} alert-dismissable">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>{messageText}</span></div>'
```

Which is not valid markup because you have a span in the middle of the button tag. The browser will try to fix it, with varying results.

Try closing the button tag and moving the span closing tag inside the button close, as follows. I have spaced things out so you can see that the tags match up.

```
alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>' + messageText 
             + '</div>';
```